# android Linear Layout Pushed by keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-softkeyboard

I have a relative layout above a linear  Layout on my screen :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/GeniusFix"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/scan"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
```

....
....

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/touchInterceptor"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/GeniusFix"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/cardthis"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

...
...
...

---

The problem is Whenever the keyboard is triggered, the linear layout gets pushed up.
(P.S: I've already added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to the manifest )
Doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Post your full layout